# Android custom view is not drawn properly

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I have a custom widget based on the Android Gallery view. It is slightly customized to show the elements from the left of the view without a gap and pass required events to my listener.

On the very first view layout everything works perfect. However when I pause and resume the activity the view freezes. It is visible, I can see OnTouch() event handlers working, view positions adjusted, but the picture is not changing. The OnDraw() method for the Gallery widget is not called at all! 
I have another widget in this layout (a sliding drawer) and as soon as I barely move the drawer everything starts working back again as it should.

I am completely out of ideas how to fix this. Tried different ways to force the OnDraw() method but it is just not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you override `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` and not `OnDraw()` (both the `Canvas` argument and the lower case initial 'o').

If it's not that, then please post some code to look at it.

Comment: I do not need to override onDraw(Canvas) method because I do not draw anything custom on the canvas. I've overridden the method only to put a trace in it and see if it is called.
I've noticed that if I run hierarchy viewer for the layout it un-freezes and starts working. So it looks like requestLayout() is not called somewhere. Tried calling requestLayout() in different places without any sucess.